# Foursquare API Help

Tags: php, json, foursquare

I'm trying to get nearby venues.  I found this url where i can just plug in lat and lon.

How do i use this URL?  I tried getting the libraries from Foursquare API site, but can't get them to work.

I know i can json_decode the result on this page to get a php object, but how do i make a call and get the data to my webpage?

https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=40.562362&geolong=-111.938689&l=10

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents(http://MyURL/);
        $results = json_decode($data, true); //true = making it into array, not object
```